# Summernote image upload with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, summernote

Im really struggling to get SummerNote to upload an iamge in .NET core. The trouble is the IFormFile file parameter is null when a new image is uploaded.

I initialise Summernote using the following -

```
$('#MessageBody').summernote({
    height: ($(window).height() - 300),
    callbacks: {
        onImageUpload: function(image) {
            uploadImage(image[0]);  
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the uploadImage function -

```
function uploadImage(image) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", image);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/EmailTemplate/UploadImage',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            success: function(url) {
                var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://' + url);
                $('#MessageBody').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
                
                alert(url);  
                var imgNode = document.createElement('img');  
                imgNode.src = url;  
                $('#MessageBody').summernote('insertNode', imgNode);  
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
```

And finally, here is the controller -

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        string message;
        var saveimg = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images", file.FileName);
        string imgext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        if (imgext == ".jpg" || imgext == ".png")
        {
            using (var uploadimg = new FileStream(saveimg, FileMode.Create))
            {

                await file.CopyToAsync(uploadimg);
                message = "The selected file" + file.FileName + " is saved";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            message = "only JPG and PNG extensions are supported";
        }
        // return "filename : " + saveimg + " message :" + message; 
        
        return Content(Url.Content(saveimg));
    }
```

Comment: The parameter is called `file` while the field name is `image`. Use the same name, either `file` or `image`. The `IFormFile` type represents the value of an `input type=file` field. The parameter name is the field's name. There may be many file fields in the same form so the type isn't enough to determine the field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos of course! Compeltely missed that one! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is called `file` while the field name is `image`. To fix this use the same name, either file or image.

The [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-6.0) type represents the value of an `input type=file` field. `IFormFile` parameters are bound to fields based on their name. There may be many file fields in the same form so the type isn't enough to determine the field.

Field binding is explained in the [Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sources) section of the [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) document.